How to simultaneously access dockerized mongodb from other containers as well as the host (using MongoDB Compass)?
Context
I have two docker containers

mymongodb
mydrf

Both the containers are under the same network "sj"
After bringing the container up, the "mymongodb" container is accessible from the host computer (Windows 11).
However, after attempting a connection from the python code in the "mydrf" container to the "mymongodb" container, the mongodb compass on the host system is unable to connect to the "mymongodb" container.
If the the containers are brought down and brought back up, compass on host is able to connect again to the "mymongodb" container.
Question
How to configure the container so as to access the mongodb from other containers as well as the host system at the same time?
Following is my docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.8'

services:
  mongo:
    image: my-db-mongo:1.0.0
    container_name: mymongodb
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./MongoDB:/data/db
    command: mongod --bind_ip_all      
    networks:
      - sj
  drf:
    image: my-drf:1.0.0
    container_name: mydrf    
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "5678:5678"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./drf
        target: /code
    networks:
      - sj
    depends_on:
      - mongo        
    command: 
      - sh
      - -c
      - |
        pip install --upgrade pip \
        && pip install pipenv \
        && pip install -r MyRequirement.txt \
        && tail -f /dev/null
networks:
  sj:
    driver: bridge

What I've tried
Tried using the following, but it did not work command:
mongod --bind_ip 0.0.0.0,host.docker.internal


Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. As you're using a non-standard mongodb image (my-db-mongo) it's hard for others to say what might be the issue. Perhaps you can try first with an official mongo image? Also, could you please [edit] into your answer what you've researched so far? What websearches did you do? What did you find? Why was it not helpful?
